# Findbugs NoClassesFoundToAnalyze Exception

Tags: java, findbugs, sonarqube

We are using Sonar for code analysis, which in turn uses findbugs i believe for the bytecode scan. The sonar execution is built within the ANT build system and is running on RHEL build host.

All of a sudden recently, the code coverage analysis started failing with the Noclasses found to analyse exception, which is puzzling when there are 7951 classes compiled in the binaries dir.

Here are the steps followed to collect the metrics
*) Compile the code first
*) Sonar target depends on unittest and triggers unittest
*) Then executes the sonar section when the target is called

```
<target name="sonar" depends="run-testng-unittest-coverage">

            <path id="sonar.classpath">
              <fileset dir="${env.projecthome}/.m2/repository/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
              <fileset dir="${env.3rdpartyhome}/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
            </path>
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="project-short-name"/>
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="PROJECT SHORT DESC"/>
    <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
    <property name="sonar.branch" value="main"/>
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://sonar.instance:9000"/>
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://sonar.instance:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="sonar"/>
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="sonar"/>
    <property name="sonar.findbugs.timeout" value="3600000"/>
    <property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="true"/>
    <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="cobertura"/>
    <property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="cobertura" />
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="src"/>
    <property name="sonar.tests" value="test/unit"/>
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="build/test/unit/classes,App/classes"/>
    <pathconvert property="sonar.libraries" pathsep="," refid="sonar.classpath"/>
    <property name="sonar.exclusions" value="orm/**/*,selenium/**/*,sql/**/*,test/**/*,xml/**/*,xsl/**/*"/>
    <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <property name="sonar.skipPackageDesign" value="true"/>
    <property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${full.path.reports.testng}/unittest/junitreports"/>
    <property name="sonar.cobertura.reportPath" value="${full.path.reports.testng}/unittest/cobertura/coverage.xml"/>
            <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="sonar.classpath" />
            <sonar:sonar key="${sonar.projectKey}" version="${sonar.projectVersion}" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
    </target>
```

Error stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.NoClassesFoundToAnalyzeException: No classes found to analyze in /opt/project/build/test/unit/classes /opt/project/App/classes

   at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:274)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Total time: 6 minutes 25 seconds

Count of total classes in the sonar binaries dir

```
find /opt/project/build/test/unit/classes /opt/project/App/classes -name "*.class" |wc -l
7951
```

Following are the version of plugins that Sonar downloads

```
    Sonar version: 3.5.1
    09:29:21.845 INFO  .s.b.b.BatchSettings - Load batch settings
    09:29:21.987 INFO     o.s.h.c.FileCache - User cache: /opt/home/user/.sonar/cache
    09:29:21.994 INFO  atchPluginRepository - Install plugins
    09:29:22.002 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:22.262 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-issues-report-plugin-1.0.jar
    09:29:29.820 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-timeline-plugin-1.3.jar
    09:29:29.878 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-clirr-plugin-1.1.jar
    09:29:29.884 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-l10n-en-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:29.890 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-scm-activity-plugin-1.5.jar
    09:29:29.964 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-sonargraph-plugin-3.0.5.jar
    09:29:30.006 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.3.jar
    09:29:30.012 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-cpd-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:30.018 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-fb-contrib-plugin-1.1.jar
    09:29:30.040 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-pmd-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:30.107 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-squid-java-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:30.144 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-technicaldebt-plugin-1.2.1.jar
    09:29:30.150 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-email-notifications-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:30.179 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-useless-code-tracker-plugin-0.5.jar
    09:29:30.330 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.4.jar
    09:29:30.441 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-quality-index-plugin-1.1.3.jar
    09:29:30.447 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:30.472 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-jira-plugin-1.0.jar
    09:29:30.547 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-surefire-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:30.554 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-ldap-plugin-1.2.1.jar
    09:29:30.565 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-checkstyle-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:39.093 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-java-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:39.100 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-core-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:39.113 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:39.118 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.2.jar
    09:29:39.123 INFO  b.b.PluginDownloader - Download sonar-design-plugin-3.5.1.jar
    09:29:39.989 INFO  .s.b.b.TaskContainer - -------------  Executing Project Scan
    09:29:40.635 INFO  b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - Install JDBC driver
    09:29:40.638 INFO  b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar
    09:29:40.663 INFO  .b.ProjectExclusions - Apply project exclusions
```

Can someone shed some light on this please..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case someone like me will end up on this question with "NoClassesFoundToAnalyze Exception" in Java 9+ era:

Firebugs is no longer supported and therefore it doesn't work with Java 9+ - [use Spotbugs instead](https://spotbugs.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs is used to check rules over compiled class, so you need to specify the target folder where ".class" files are allocated.

You should review the target directorry at findbug execution time.

Comment: Yes, the classes lie inside build/test/unit/classes,App/classes which is specified in sonar binaries.  It definitely worked in the past.

Comment: I ended up disabling findbugs from sonar plugins, but that's just a  interim workaround to see the actual percentage of CC. I still have to get to the root of the evil cause..

Comment: How do you tell the sonar findbugs plugin where to look for class files?